# Awesome WM Does not Search for Wifi Networks?

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager, awesome

When I start Awesome WM, it works fine but it does not start the daemon/application that searches for and connects to wifi networks.

How to make it do that both on startup as well as on demand since I may want it to do so only on demand?

Comment: Did you resolve your question?

Answer (score 4):

I presume you want to start something like `nm-applet`.  To do so "on demand", you would type at the command line: `nm-applet &`.

If you want to autostart it, you can autostart it like any other app in Awesome.  In `rc.lua` add a new line:

```
awful.util.spawn_with_shell("nm-applet &")
```

to the section with your autostart apps; if you don't have such a section, just add it at the end.

If you restart Awesome, it'll run `nm-applet` again, which is annoying.  So I actually suggest using:

```
awful.util.spawn_with_shell("pgrep -u $USER -x nm-applet > /dev/null || (nm-applet &)")
```

This will ensure `nm-applet` has exactly one running instance.

Comment: Thanks! Just a minor addition: For Awesome 4+, use `awful.spawn.with_shell` to avoid a deprecation warning.

Answer (score 3):

Press the <kbd>Super</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. Check your network-manager service status by typing this commands:

`sudo service network-manager status`

If it is up and running, check the available wifi networks:

`nmcli con list`

To connect:

`nmcli con up id (the name of your wifi networks)`